# Including d.ts type definition files in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've started using VSCode 0.7.0 and noticed the notes say you don't have to add `///` references anymore:

> With the introduction of jsconfig.json, you no longer need to use /// references in each file (these were required in the initial versions of VS Code). As the file set is defined in jsconfig.json, VS Code knows what files and symbols are part of your project.
>
> As an example, you can just drop a new type definition .d.ts file into your project folder and VS Code will pick it up automatically.

However, I dropped many such files in the `typings` folder and it doesn't seem VSCode recognizes them. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Try restarting VSCode everytime you add a reference..

Comment: Restarting did not help for me

Comment: Restarting VSCode after adding a reference works for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is the `jsconfig.json` file I'm using:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "files": [
            "typings/node/node.d.ts"
        ]
    }
}
```

The `typings` folder exists alongside the `jsconfig.json` file at the root of the project.

If you highlight an unknown global such as `__dirname` in nodejs then hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> on PC?) then select `Download typings` they will be created for you.

Comment: I don't know changed, but this throws errors about the fact that `files` is an unknown compiler option.

Answer (score 0):

This is true, the caveat is that the typings folder must be in the same directory as your tsconfig.json.

Comment: I use ES6 JS, and the folder is in the same directory as jsconfig.json

Comment: You can reference the repo I have here which is setup to have typings & tsconfig under the `src` directory, notice how I have no usage of /// <ref... https://github.com/Brocco/ng-bridge

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a tsconfig.json file or a jsconfig.json file? The latter is required when authoring js files, the former for ts files.